# Does anyone recognise this plant?

Tags: identification, houseplants, indoors, office-gardening

We have a plant in our office that came from another office and has no label. It has started growing some interesting flowers. Just wondering if anyone knows what it is?

[image: Mystery plant]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is most likely [Dracaena fragrans](https://www.google.de/search?client=firefox-b-ab&noj=1&biw=1683&bih=965&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=dracaena+fragrans+blossom&oq=dracaena+fragrans+blossom&gs_l=img.3...15969.16862.0.17474.6.6.0.0.0.0.102.453.5j1.6.0....0...1c.1.64.img..0.1.90...0j0i24k1.Pc15VZ0ZcU0), in my humble opinion it's the classical office plant.

It's interesting that it started to flourish as it almost always just dies over time.

Comment: Thanks Stephan. Yes it seems to be doing ok in our office. Odd because I had another different plant that I took home because I felt sorry for it because it wasn't doing very well at all. That one looked loads happier when I got it home. But this one seems ok here.

Comment: Flowering profusely sometimes means the plant is dying and is using the last dregs of its energy to make seed to be perpetuated.

Comment: This 'corn plant' is very tough.  In my experience it can put up with massive abuse and still thrive.

Comment: Oh dear, that would make sense, I don't think plants like it in our office. Even though I nearly killed the one I mentioned earlier when I took it home on the bus (accidentally pulled all the leaves off) it still ended up doing a lot better at home that it ever did in the office. Maybe I should take this one home as well, lol.

Answer (score 2):

Dracaena / corn plant. As Stormy said, it tolerates serious abuse ( and lives). I have one that has descended from a 6" length I started over 50 years ago.  The bloom shows conditions have been good ; usually the flower smells so bad it is cut off.I have seen them 25+ feet tall in greenhouse conditions.